# Why does ViewRecycler explode onMeasure

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have ViewRecycler using CardView's inside a Fragment which is part of a ViewPager on an ActionBarActivity. All of these things from the Support libraries.

When I try to open the application it crashes with the following exception. Is there a known problem or solution I've missed?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:1764)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16736)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16736)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5178)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16736)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5178)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16736)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5178)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16736)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5178)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16736)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5178)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2392)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16736)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2095)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1208)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1394)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1095)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6010)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:799)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:599)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:784)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried various suggestions such as using LinearLayouts anywhere I have a RelativeLayout, but nothing helped so I reverted back. My layouts and code are as follows

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class LaunchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.me.LaunchActivity" />
```

**Fragment**

```
public class RotaFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mCardRecycler;

    public static RotaFragment newInstance() {
        ...
    }

    public RotaFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rota, container, false);
        mCardRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler);
        return rootView;
   }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        List<WorkingFortnight> dummy = new ArrayList<>();
        ....
        mCardRecycler.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) );
        mCardRecycler.setAdapter(new RotaCardAdapter(dummy));
    }
}
```

**Fragment Layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_recycler"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

**Adapter** (set on the ViewRecycler to setup the CardViews)

```
public class RotaCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RotaCardAdapter.RotaViewHolder> {

    private List<WorkingFortnight> mRotas;

    public RotaCardAdapter(List<WorkingFortnight> rotas) {
        mRotas = rotas;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public RotaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rota_card, parent, false);
        return new RotaViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RotaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WorkingFortnight rota = mRotas.get(position);
        holder.setHours( ... );
    }

    public class RotaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mCaption;
        private RotaListAdapter mListAdapter;

        public RotaViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            ...
            mList.setAdapter(...);
        }

        ...
     }
```

**Adapter View** (The cards)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/card_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/wk01"
            android:contentDescription="@string/label_card"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/card_caption"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_image"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView android:id="@+id/card_rota"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I realise this is a complex nested layout but I'm hoping somebody knows of some issue with something I've done here, maybe certain views cant be nested but nothing has come up in my searches, and simplifying things to test hasn't helped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking the layouts apart piece by piece I've found the onMeasure exception on triggers when the fragment with the RecyclerView is nested within a ViewPager (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager). Using a simple FrameView as the activity layout avoids this issue.

*I'm not marking this as the accepted answer for the next 48 hours - if you know why, have a workaround for this or have managed to find a related bug (I didn't) report please post it and I will consider accepting your answer and removing thsi comment from my own answer, thanks*

Answer (score 1):

The null pointer occurs because the layout manager of your Recycler view is null.

You have to set the layoutmanager sooner :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rota, container, false);
    mCardRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler);
    List<WorkingFortnight> dummy = new ArrayList<>();
    ....
    mCardRecycler.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager(MyApplication.getApplicationContext()) );
    mCardRecycler.setAdapter(new RotaCardAdapter(dummy));
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this, unfortunately still have the same issue